# Polygon outline in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, symbology

I want to get a style for the polygon outline in QGIS with a dash or dot line that fits together perfectly, so that the dashes or dots that make up the outline overlap 100%.

Screenshot for understanding, normally both lines should be black.

[image]

Comment: What are the red and green lines in your example? What have you tried and what is not working?

Comment: Aligning dashes is difficult and your use case is even more difficult because you need different colors and converting polygon boundaries into a line layer without any overlaps does not work. Find same kind of questions https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=polygon+dashed+line.

Comment: This will also depend on the number of overlapping polygons and the overlap can be different on different sides of the polygon meaning the dashes could be different length along the border and the offsets would be different. It might be possible but would require a lot of geometry calculations on the fly.

Comment: The placement of dashes and dots depends on the map scale, extent of the map, position of the feature on that extent, etc. Moreover, this algorithm is not even compatible with the algorithm for placing marker lines at intervals.

Comment: If both lines need to be black, you could convert your polygon layer to a line layer and flatten it (say run v.clean and then the remove duplicates) and use that for your symbology.  You could still  have a polygons layer for other purposes which not symbolized.  Of course every change in the polys requires making a new line layer for the symbology.  Another option would be to make your symbology a series of black with white dashes in between, so the top poly line blocks out the lower, but you probably are using dashes so you can see under the lines, so it would have to be special case.